# The meaning of し

Tags: words, particle-し

I didn't understand し after 買った

> 旅行の計画は終わった？
>   うん、切符を買ったし、ホテルの予約もしてある。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**し** is used to emphatically add information to a statement, implying that something **is** among other things(that may be not mentioned as well). The simple formula is as follows:

- **Verbs:** Informal termination + し
- **i-Adjs:** i-Adj+し:　美味しい → 美味しいし.
- **na-Adjs/nouns:** na-Adj/noun + だし:　静か → 静かだし

e.g. その喫茶店は料理が美味しいし、値段がひくいし、それに駐車場があるし。
　　　　
The food on that restaurant is delicious(**among the next facts**), **also** the prices are low, and what's more, they **also** have parking.

We can see the emphatically adding of information here with the rough translations for **し**.

---

This **し** pattern is normally written or spoken with more than 1 **し** on the sentence, however, you can have only one **し** on the sentences and end with it (although is sometimes not seen as correct).

おいトムくん、もう彼女ができたの？ - Hey Tom, have you gotten yourself a girl already?

彼女？！時間がないし… Girlfriend?! I don't have time for that(**among other reasons**).

Answer (score 5):

This し is an emphatic 'and'.

> 切符を買ったし、ホテルの予約もしてある。
>   I bought a ticket **and what's more** the hotel's been booked.